# function clickbutton sin jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo un codigo que hace click en un boton, pero quiero hacer lo mismo sin jquery, ya que jquery pone muy lenta mi página, como lo hago con javascript? este es el codigo:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
        setTimeout(clickbutton,5000);

        function clickbutton()
        {
            $("#botonEnviar").click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, pero quisiera hacer referencia a que jQuery es una librería muy liviana y no creo que sea jQuery lo que te lo hace lento, tal vez estás llamando varios estilos css.

Pero a la pregunta, cómo hacer lo que tienes sin jQuery.
La forma en la que yo lo hago:

En el body (esto hace que la función clickbutton se ejecute al abrirse la página.

```
<body onload="clickbutton()">
```

Luego en el html de tu boton, supongamos que lo tengas algo así

```
<button id="botonEnviar" onclick="clickbutton()">Enviar</button>
```

Luego tu script

```
<script>
        function clickbutton()
        {
            //todo tu código de la función
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo este ejemplo, espero te ayude a orientarte para tu situación

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn">Hola</button>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
         clickbutton()
      }, 5000)
    })
    
    function clickbutton(){
      let btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
      btn.innerHTML = "Me diste click"
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hago uso de un listener para escuchar cuando el `DOM` esta "listo" a través de `DOMContentLoaded` y entonces invoco a la función `setTimeout` que por dentro recibe el nombre de mi función personalizada y el tiempo asignado.

Por fuera de la lectura del `DOM`, desarrollo mi función personalizada, donde con `querySelector()` obtengo el id del elemento HTML que deseo obtener

Por fines de ejemplo con el método innerHTML modifico el contenido del `button` para mostrar la funcionalidad del código recién creado

> Para el caso de poder revisar cuando el DOM esta cargado, esta
>   disponible de este modo

```
self.addEventListener ...
document.addEventListener ...
window.addEventListener ...
```